# Do not insert duplicates into mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a method that inserts into table `NKP`:

```py
def insert_nkp(self, kniha):
    query = """
            INSERT INTO NKP SET
                id_product = %s,
                supplier_reference = %s, 
                nazev = %s, 
                nazev_orig = %s, 
                hlavni_zahlavi = %s,
                preklad_z = %s,
                zanr = %s, 
                nakladatel = %s, 
                vydani = %s,
                rozsah = %s

            """

    self.cursor.execute(query, kniha)
    self.connection.commit()
```

But I want to insert into `NKP` only if there is not existing the same `id_product`. I tried to add

```sql
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id_product = VALUES(id_product)
```

but it did not help. What is the most elegant way how to do this, please?

Comment: Please read the answers carefully, particularly on the role of primary keys / unique indexes!

Comment: @Shadow thank you for the reply. If I understand it correctly, I need to set `id_product` as a primary key, before I use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax?

Comment: or as a unique index - depending on what your pk is.